# What does "accommodate" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A draft of the main G20 communique seen by Reuters appeared to **accommodate** Trump's views on trade by dropping a phrase resisting "all forms of protectionism."

Source: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-germany-G20-document-exclusive-idUSKBN16M0SG (emphasis added)

What does "accommodate" mean in this context?

Comment: I use this link: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/accommodate?q=accommodate+

Comment: By the way, while I'm OK with "agree" as Mithrandir suggests, I would like to add that I feel "accommodate" also implies an "active" agreement, that is, there had to be a change for the agreement to come about. Using your link, I would suggest definition three: A draft of the main G20 communique seen by Reuters appeared to *consider and be influenced by* Trump's views on trade by dropping a phrase resisting "all forms of protectionism."

Comment: I would say that the word **accommodate** is misused here. The G20 has no room for protectionism.  Only if the communique had said something like "resisting all forms of protectionism *except where there is an egregious imbalance of trade*", could one say that it appeared to accommodate Trump's views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accommodate here means that the communique *agrees* with those views. One of the definitions on [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/accommodate) is:

> 10. to become reconciled; agree.