# Which definition of accommodate is the best in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I [printed out all definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44474499/3552975) of "accommodate":

```
Synset('suit.v.01') be agreeable or acceptable to
Synset('adapt.v.01') make fit for, or change to suit a new purpose
Synset('accommodate.v.03') provide with something desired or needed
Synset('accommodate.v.04') have room for; hold without crowding
Synset('lodge.v.04') provide housing for
Synset('oblige.v.03') provide a service or favor for someone
Synset('accommodate.v.07') make (one thing) compatible with (another)
```

but cannot decide which one fits [this context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6509106/3552975)(by someone from the USA) most:

> I prefer the solution to be flexible so that if the list grows to 200 items, I don't have to do a lot of manual adjustments to accommodate the new list.

I've searched ell.stackexchange.com and thought these two are the most related: [make adjustments that help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/174787/10484) and [to become reconciled; agree.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/122555/10484).

Using [the word sense disambiguation technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24356325/3552975), I get the most suitable definition:

```
sent = "I prefer the solution to be flexible so that if the list grows to 200 items, I don't have to do a lot of manual adjustments to accommodate the new list."
ambiguous = "accommodate"
lesk(sent, ambiguous).definition()
# 'provide a service or favor for someone'
```

Is 'provide a service or favor for someone'('oblige.v.03') the best one from all its 7 definitions above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any given context, some of these definitions might mean the same thing. However, in your example, the best fit is probably the second:

> make fit for, or change to suit a new purpose

> ... I don't have to (1) *do a lot of manual adjustments* to accommodate (2) *the new list*

(1) change the solution so that it works with
(2) a list of 200

Because of the context, you could also argue that these would work:

> have room for; hold without crowding

> make (one thing) compatible with (another)

The definition you chose:

- provide a service or favor for someone

is not really appropriate because it's intended to be used when you're providing a service or favor to a **person**, and in this case you're talking about a list, which is an object, not a human being. Here's a better example for that definition:

> We need to adjust the seating to better accommodate his wheelchair.

Comment: Then I wonder if the definition('oblige.v.03') chosen by machine is correct? Maybe not the best.

Comment: By "correct" I mean "acceptable"

Comment: Probably not, because you're not providing a service to someone (a human being). I'll add to my answer above because I didn't address that.